# Trying to create a multidimensional array with the calendar module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I am working with currently and that I want to create a multidimensional array of the year 2020 using all the months:

```
import calendar

a = calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 1), calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 2)
print(a)
""" 
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 2))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 3))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 4))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 5))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 6))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 7))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 8)) 
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 9))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 10))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 11))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020, 12))
"""
```

Comment: (1) The shown code is syntactically incorrect. Fix the formatting of the question. (2) Show the full traceback (error message) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It now gives me a rudimentary array of the first 2 months and no error message

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension to get all the weeks of 2020 using the `monthcalendar` of Python's `calendar`module

https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html

(Returns a matrix representing a month’s calendar. Each row represents a week; days outside of the month a represented by zeros. Each week begins with Monday)

```
from calendar import monthcalendar

weeks_2020 = [monthcalendar(2020, i) for i in range(1, 13)]

for week in weeks_2020:
    print(week)
```

Result:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: why do we use a for week in weeks_2020 and then print week rather than just print(weeks_2020)? Like what does the for loop and the introduction of the new variable week do? thank you

Comment: `week` is an iterator which is used to loop through the iterable `weeks_2020`. You do not need it and you can directly print `weeks_2020` but that will be less readable. Here is a 4 min read as introduction: https://towardsdatascience.com/iterators-iterables-in-python-e713a55dfe1f#:~:text=Iterables%20are%20objects%20that%20have,us%20to%20access%20subsequent%20values.&text=Put%20simply%2C%20iterators%20are%20what's,every%20for%2Dloop%20in%20python.